# Tracking an object via OpenCV

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, object, tracking

I am trying to track an object (a ball in this case) using OpenCV and Python. As example I am using this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmQZiSOiD1c

What I need is to keep track on the ball without detecting other parts of the video as the ball. Tracking by colour doesn't work here. Finding circles is quite tricky for the same reason.

And idea for a good approach on this problem?

Comment: Search for probabilistic tracking (e.g. particle filtering) in computer vision literature. Dont expect it to be easy for hard background or unclear foreground.

Comment: Will do. Any specific literature you can recommend?

Comment: I found "Color-BasedProbabilisticTracking" by Perez to be a good paper about particle filtering. For basics see wikipedia and google, there are some nice teacher slides

Answer (score 0):

A simple tracking of the ball might be carried out by first :

1. Isolating the foosball table using perspective homography i.e. constructing a plan view of the table to make tracking 2D position easier.
2. Making a series of observations (guesses) using a simple method, to remove background using colour and/or motion.

Any probabilistic type tracking (including particle filtering) requires making a series of observations. Making good quality observations is key in producing good tracking results.

Here is some [source code](http://pastebin.com/uwv3CHsW) which does a basic hough circle analysis on the video you provided and the [results](http://tinypic.com/r/312xy5k/8). Note that the green point is not a bad approximation for the past and current position of the ball. The next step would be to use particle filtering on the color data with the position calculated by simple hough analysis. You also might like to use a search window around the current positions to filter out any false positives.

Also, injecting some noise into the image can improve tracking results as it provides feature detectors false edges to latch onto.

Before investing a lot of time in getting a good particle filter to work using python, I've found the performance of [TLD](https://github.com/gnebehay/OpenTLD) & [CMT](https://github.com/gnebehay/CMT) trackers to be excellent for this kind of work.

Comment: Woah this is great! I am just a bit confused why you hardly get any results that are not the ball while mine is finding the wrong target a bit too often. I would look into TLD/CMT, but I have to work with Python. When I learn C++ somewhen I will look into it :)